# Doxygen not updating comments for duplicate files

Tags: file, duplicates, comments, doxygen

I am using doxygen to provide comments to some .c and .h files (file level comments only). There are some files which are duplicated (same name) and are present in different subfolders. So, when I provide comments for these files, doxygen is not updating it in the generated html file.

I read doxygen command description provided at below link and tried providing the path for such files to make them unique but that also not working.

http://www.doxygen.nl/commands.html#cmdfile

The options I tried till now are as below. Consider, Nm.h is the file having multiple copies:

`1.   /*! \file Nm.h
        * \brief Header file
      */
2.   /*! \file \sgdcc\checkdrive\test\Nm.h
        * \brief Header file
      */
3.   /*! \file sgdcc\checkdrive\test\Nm.h
        * \brief Header file
      */`

Comments are not getting updated even for a single file. I tried providing short path as well as full path but nothing is working.

I am compliling doxygen through ClearCase and the doxygen version used in it is 1.8.2

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the backslashes in the paths with "normal" slashes. E.g.:

```
  /*! \file Nm.h
    * \brief Header file
  */

 /*! \file /sgdcc/checkdrive/test/Nm.h
    * \brief Header file
  */

 /*! \file sgdcc/checkdrive/test/Nm.h
    * \brief Header file
  */
```

You are using the backslash in the paths which is an control character indicating that a command is following. Paths should always contain normal slashes.

Comment: @Michael: Done, Thank you... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gmug. I tried implementing your suggestion but its still not working. Is there any other issue due to which its not working.

Comment: @AnShU: In this case provide more information, please. But anyway you should avoid using the backslashes in your pathes.